# Build a formula based on some cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The solution I'm looking for is a non-vba one, hopefully there's any.

[image: Build a formula]

I'm planning to build a formula at `B7`, something like `=SUM(B3:B5)`, but the value `B3` and `B5` is taken from `C7` and `D7`.

I'm working on a weekly employee salary tables, a sheet can contain some employee salary tables, broken down into week by week, using the ordinary `SUM` function will take more efforts, so I'm looking for an easier way to do it.

Any clues would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look up INDIRECT formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution, use the following formula:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(C7,":",D7)))
```

- `CONCATENATE` to join both cells in order to form the range `C7:D7`.
- `INDIRECT` to transform your text into a valid range.
- `SUM` to sum the specified range.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this you could also choose to show the total value in a different column and a simple `=sum($B:$B)` would do.
But above is the answer to your specific question.